# Expected Field not Found by ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, cursor, runtimeerror

Currently my script kicking out:

> Runtime Error: An expected Field was not found or could not be retrieved

I did some checks and the spelling of the fields are correct and the fields do exist in the feature layer.  The line below is the error.

for mat, sId in sCur:

```
listFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields("Target_Services")] 
print listFields
for field in [srvMatFld, serviceID]:
    if field not in listFields:
        print field
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("Target_Services", [srvMatFld, serviceID]) as sCur:
    for mat, sId in sCur:
```

Comment: it's for row in sCur, it's not a tuple. you access the fields by row[0] and row[1] for srvMatFld and serviceID respectively.

Comment: What are the values of `srvMatFld` and `serviceID`?  Do these actually exist in `listFields`?  If your fields exist, then your code should work (although it's a little unorthodox), but if one or both don't exist then you will get that error.

Comment: @Luke that's the first time I've seen it done that way, is that only for search cursor or can an update cursor be addressed in the same manner?

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson Yes it will, but you'd need to pass it as tuple `cursor.updateRow((a, b))`, and in the same order!

Comment: @Midavalo the fields do exist.  I included the check in the first 5 lines of the provided coded.  It passes by not printing anything out.  Also you can use this format for Update Cursors as well.  By only calling out the fields it allows for less blunders by the auther by miss counting rows.

Comment: @
kShort have you tried explicitly naming the fields in your cursor?  `arcpy.da.SearchCursor ("Target_Services", ["ActualsrvMatFld", "ActualServiceID"]) `

Comment: The problem was not at this portion of the code.  I was using an incorrect SQL query to create the "Target_Services" feature layer.  By using a wrong field name in the query it doesn't break the script, it just keeps going until the layer can't properly be read in  a later portion of the script as in there is no "row" for the cursor to read.  Thanks for all of the insight.

Answer (score 4):

One or both of your fields in `srvMatFld` and `serviceID` don't exist.  Could be a typo in your parameter(s).

Here is my test script based on your code (I've just added a few extra print statements to make things stand out:

```
import arcpy 
print "######################################################"
xx = r"d:\gis\se\gisse.gdb\testpoint"
srvMatFld = 'intfield'
serviceID = 'dblfield'

listFields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(xx)] 
print listFields

print "######################################################"
for field in [srvMatFld, serviceID]:
    if field not in listFields:
        print field

print "######################################################"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(xx, [srvMatFld, serviceID]) as cursor:
    for x, y in cursor:
        print x, y

print "######################################################"
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(xx, [srvMatFld, serviceID]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0], row[1]
```

And the output:

```
######################################################
[u'OBJECTID', u'SHAPE', u'textfield', u'intfield', u'dblfield', u'datefield', u'SampleText', u'leisure', u'Greenspace', u'Name', u'Description', u'BigNumbers', u'TestVBA', u'MyDblField', u'MyIncrementField']
######################################################
######################################################
123 23.56
5454 -12234.2341
68465 None
5151 None
None None
######################################################
123 23.56
5454 -12234.2341
68465 None
5151 None
None None
>>>
```

However, if I put a typo in one of my two field names (in this case `srvMatFld = 'intfieldx'`) then I get the error you encounter:

```
######################################################
[u'OBJECTID', u'SHAPE', u'textfield', u'intfield', u'dblfield', u'datefield', u'SampleText', u'leisure', u'Greenspace', u'Name', u'Description', u'BigNumbers', u'TestVBA', u'MyDblField', u'MyIncrementField']
######################################################
intfieldx
######################################################
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GIS\VSProjects\GISTest\GISSE\GISSE\xScratch.py", line 42, in <module>
    for x, y in cursor:
RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist.
>>>
```

Note the incorrect field name `intfieldx` is specified from the `if field not in listFields: print field` this time.

Your cursor loop is a little unorthodox - usually you'd loop through something like `for row in cursor:`, but if the fields exist, the way you've written it *should* still work.

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(xx, [srvMatFld, serviceID]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        print row[0], row[1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I was trying to run a Search Cursor on an empty feature layer.  I didn't check to see if the feature layer was actually correct.  Sorry for taking up your time but thanks for the insight!